# Looking for a way to link 2 list back together in python

Tags: python, list

I basically have 1 list: list [(name 1, score 1), (name 2, score 2) etc]. I use the scores in another list to randomize those based on an algorithm but after that I would like to link every score back to each name. The scores can be the same, but it doesn't matter. If 2 scores are the sames with different names, it doesn't matter which score gets linked to which name because the score is the same. Please help!

INPUT: 
list1 = [(0, a), (100, b), (200, c), (300, d)] 
list2 = [[200, 0], [300, 100]]

EXPECTED OUTPUT: 
list3 = [[(200, c), (0, a)], [(300, d), (100, b)]]

How do i get list3 from list2 and list1?

*list1 = [(0, a), (0, b), (0, c), (0, d)] is also a valid list.

It then doesn't matter if
list3 = [[(0, a), (0, b)], [(0, c), (0, d)]] OR 
list3 = [[(0, d), (0, b)], [(0, c), (0, a)]]*

Comment: Please provide [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Welcome to the stackoverflow, it would be nice if you can add a little bit of code to show what your expected result might look like.

Comment: where is another list and what do you mean by randomize?

Comment: I basically have a list with 30 names and scores IN ORDER. I take all the scores into a separate list and randomize them (this part doesnt matter), and afterwards I need to assign each score back to its original name. It is for teammaking.

Comment: What you provided is _not_ a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: [0, 0, 1600, 1200, 2075, 1099, 1300, 890, 1180, 800, 1418, 400, 1369, 0, 1263, 0, 1265, 1166, 2100, 2067, 1744, 1823, 1446, 1800, 1602, 1517, 1038, 1180, 1707, 1795] This is what the list looks like after randomization.

Comment: Still, this is not a minimal reproducible example. In other words, I can't copy-paste it and run to see the problem.

Comment: INPUT:
list1 = [(0, a), (100, b), (200, c), (300, d)]
list2 = [200, 0, 300, 100]

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
list3 = [(200, c), (0, a), (300, d), (100, b)]

How do i get list3 from list2 and list1?

Comment: Then show us input, expected output, and how have you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: I tried to start working but have nothing. It seems simple but I just can't comprehend how to make it but I need it.

Comment: I think that, while what Victor provided is not a "working example," it is a legitimate explanation of the expected input and output. He's got a lookup table in list1, and he's got a structure in list2 which he needs to fill in with the looked-up values. Is that a valid interpretation, @Victor?

Comment: So, after my answer was shown to be not good because it didn't allow for duplicates, here's a thought that I don't have time to type up right now: Iterate through list2 and create a dict from score to location. Then iterate through list1, filling in the locations as designated by that dict.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's this going to be used for?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort `list1` with a custom key function, though this is likely quite slow:

```py
def sort_by_order_in_other_list(other_list):
    def _inner(tup):
        return other_list.index(tup[0])
    return _inner

list3 = sorted(list1, key=sort_by_order_in_other_list(list2))
```

This might be the optimal algorithm for very small lists. For longer lists, I'd recommend doing a first pass to make `list2` easier to reference:

```py
dict2 = {i: value for i, value in enumerate(list2)}

list3 = sorted(list1, key=lambda x: dict2[x[0]])
```

Comment: Hey @Adam, I updated the question itself. List 2 is sorted into sublist (and those numbers have to stay inside the sublists). Is there any way you can help me with the new question asked? It is important that the numbers stay in each sublist.

Answer (score 0):

Your first list looks like a lookup table. I think the fastest way to do this conversion is to convert list1 to a dict, then do lookups to convert list2 to list3:

```
dict1 = dict(list1)

list3 = [[(item, dict1[item]) for item in sublist] for sublist in list2]

# output: [[(200, 'c'), (0, 'a')], [(300, 'd'), (100, 'b')]]
```

Python dicts have a constructor which takes a list of pairs, just like your `list1`. This turns `list1` into a fast lookup table `dict1`. Then you iterate through your sublists, then iterate through the items in each sublist, and you perform that lookup.

I don't remember the efficiency of the Python dict constructor, but it's no worse than `O(n log(n))`.

Whenever you've got a list of pairs, sometimes it's worth thinking about whether it would be easier to use it as a dict. Python loves dicts.

---

EDIT: Note that dicts can only store one value per key. While I originally thought this was OK, this was clarified to not be the case.

The next solution is to convert it to a multimap, and then destroy it as you go. A multimap is like a dict, but it stores a list of all the values that have the key --- it's not restricted to one value per key. Obviously since we don't want the entire list, we only want one unique value per instance, we'll take the last value off of the list from the map. The code will look very similar, but building the multimap will look different from building the dict did.

I'll provide a bit of a more complete example here to demonstrate.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def impose_structure (list1, list2):
    # This multimap will be a map from the key to a list of all values of that key,
    # like {0: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
    multimap = defaultdict (list)

    for key, value in list1:
        multimap[key].append (value)

    # We'll do the same thing as before, but now we'll remove values from the end
    # so we don't have duplicates
    return [[(item, multimap[item].pop ()) for item in sublist] for sublist in list2]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1 = [(0, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (100, 'c'), (100, 'd')]
    list2 = [[100, 0], [0, 100]]

    print (impose_structure (list1, list2))

# outputs: [[(100, 'd'), (0, 'b')], [(0, 'a'), (100, 'c')]]
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your method and it is good if everything is unique. What I meant is that  **list1 = [(0, a), (0, b), (0, c), (0, d)] ** is also a valid list. It then doesn't matter if **list3 = [[(0, a), (0, b)], [(0, c), (0, d)]] OR list3 = [[(0, d), (0, b)], [(0, c), (0, a)]]. Unfortunately, your code then produces an error. :(

Comment: In your code, it would give list 3 = [[(0, a), (0, a)], [(0, a), (0, a)]]

Comment: Yep, as stated in the disclaimer at the end! I misunderstood your question, so maybe you should update your example input and output so that's unambiguous.

Comment: I did, if you have the time to somehow create that code in the next day that would be amazing, im pretty new at coding and i'm sorry for posing a wrong written question.

Comment: @VictorvandenDijk, I updated this answer, and I think it should meet the criteria you've got. If it solves your problem, it would be helpful to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your list1 is in the format that a dictionary would accept and what you are looking to do is to substitute values with their indexed counterpart of such a dictionary.  So the simplest way will be to turn list1 into an actual dictionary and use it in a list comprehension to map the values of list2:

```
list1 = [(0, "a"), (100, "b"), (200, "c"), (300, "d")]
list2 = [[200, 0], [300, 100]]

dict1 = dict(list1)    
list3 = [ [(i,dict1[i]) for i in r] for r in list2 ]

print(list3)
[[(200, 'c'), (0, 'a')], [(300, 'd'), (100, 'b')]]
```